# WebRTC channel reliability

Tags: webrtc, rtcdatachannel, rtcpeerconnection

I'd like to check my understanding of WebRTC data channels is correct, in particular the different types of channels that can be achieved by varying the `ordered` & `maxRetransmits` or `maxPacketLifeTime` properties to the `RTCDataChannelInit` dictionary. Are my below assumptions correct:

1. Creates a **reliable** & **ordered** channel, like TCP but message based instead of stream:

> ```
> RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel("label", {
>     ordered: true 
> });
> ```

2. Creates a **reliable** but **unordered** channel (should `maxRetransmits` or `maxPacketLifeTime` be specified too to achieve reliability?)

> ```
> RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel("label", {
>         ordered: false    
> });
> ```

3. Creates a **unreliable** and **unordered** channel, like UDP

> ```
> RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel("label", {
>     ordered: false,
>     maxRetransmits: 0
> });
> ```

4. Creates a **unreliable** but **"sequenced"** channel i.e. earlier messages will be dropped if arriving after later ones

> ```
> RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel("label", {
>     ordered: true,
>     maxRetransmits: 0
> });
> ```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of your assumptions are correct.

---

For the first and second case, not setting `maxRetransmits` and `maxPacketLifeTime` results in a **reliable** channel according to the [section 6.2 RTCDataChannel of WebRTC W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#rtcdatachannel), which is the following (bold and italics mine):

> An `RTCDataChannel` can be configured to operate in different reliability modes. A reliable channel ensures that the data is delivered at the other peer through retransmissions. An unreliable channel is configured to either limit the number of retransmissions ( `maxRetransmits` ) or set a time during which transmissions (including retransmissions) are allowed ( `maxPacketLifeTime` ). These properties can not be used simultaneously and an attempt to do so will result in an error. ***Not setting any of these properties results in a reliable channel.***

---

The third case, which is setting `ordered: false` and `maxRetransmits: 0`, creates an **unreliable** and **unordered** channel like UDP according to [RFC8831 section 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8831#section-6.1), which is the following (bold and italics mine):

> - The partial reliability extension defined in [RFC3758] MUST be
>   supported.  In addition to the timed reliability PR-SCTP policy
>   defined in [RFC3758], the limited retransmission policy defined in
>   [RFC7496] MUST be supported.  ***Limiting the number of
>   retransmissions to zero, combined with unordered delivery,
>   provides a UDP-like service*** where each user message is sent
>   exactly once and delivered in the order received.

---

The fourth case, which is setting `ordered: true` and `maxRetransmits: 0`, creates an **unreliable** but **ordered**(**"sequenced"**) channel. This type of channel exists according to a paragraph of [RFC3758 section 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3758#section-1.3), which is the following (bold and italics mine):

> 3. In addition to providing unordered, unreliable data transfer as UDP does, PR-SCTP can provide ***ordered, unreliable*** data transfer service.

---

About the fourth case, I don't know exactly how **"ordered"** is implemented on an **"unreliable"** data channel. But I think the guess in here https://jameshfisher.com/2017/01/17/webrtc-datachannel-reliability/ would be right. The receiver may discard earlier messages if they arrive after later ones.

This guess seems right according to the last paragraph of [RFC3758 section 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3758#section-3.6), which is the following (bold and italics mine):

> Note that after receiving a FORWARD TSN and updating the cumulative
> acknowledgement point, if a TSN that was skipped does arrive (i.e.,
> due to network reordering), then the receiver will follow the normal
> rules defined in RFC 2960 [2] for handling duplicate data.  This
> implies that ***the receiver will drop the chunk*** and report it as a
> duplicate in the next outbound SACK chunk.

[RFC3758](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3758) is refered by [RFC8831 section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8831#section-5), which is, in turn, refered by [WebRTC W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#bib-rfc8831).

Answer (score 0):

First three assumptions are correct, the fourth assumption is not correct.

As per the webrtc-pc specification maxPacketLifeTime or maxRetransmits can only be used in unreliable mode.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dfn-maxretransmits

The fourth case creates the reliable & ordered channel.

More info - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/